# Animate transform matrix using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

How would one transform matrix using .animate() with JQuery from

```
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30);
```

to

```
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -30);
```

tried this but doesn't work:

```
$(".elm").fadeIn()
.css({transform:"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30)"
     })
.animate({transform:"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -30)"}, 800, function() {
    //callback
});
```

also tried:

```
$(".elm").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 30)")
.animate("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -30)", 800, function() {
    //callback
});
```

pen: https://codepen.io/uiunicorn/pen/XWpweZG

I could use `translateY()` but that's not the point I'm interested to why the above won't work.

Comment: Hi, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2695yhxw/) you mean ?

Comment: @Swati Hi thanks for the reply and no in your example the element jumps straight to -30 instead of animating to -30 im in need of it animating like so: 30,29,28,27,26,25,24 etc etc till it gets to -30 so with animate if i animate the top: css for example it will over the number inbetween and animate